# Best way to get content from a webserver when it's busy?

Tags: java, http, tcp

I have the below code to connect a webserver and get content via http request and everything is Ok. But sometimes that website is really being busy, taking to many request at the same time from different users, since I do not know how the http servers work exactly, Is there any tricks that I can do to get content rapidly, in your mind.

I use the below code in multi threaded, every 5 milisecond to get the content when the website is updated to get data instantly.

Can I keep the connection open? Does it make sense, or anything else that makes me get the data earlier when it is really busy?

```
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
url.openConnection();                 

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) result.append(inputLine);
in.close();  
content = result.toString();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes I imagine the server is busy if you're hitting it with 200 requests per second per client. If you control the server, then you can look into one of the various ways to implement streaming content from the server (websockets, chunked transfer encoding, etc.)

Comment: This is like a kid asking how to get the full attention of the teacher and make him/her ignore all the other kids which also need help. Even if there would be a way to achieve this it would be first unfair to all the other kids and second you can be sure that the other kids would use this way too after a while which causes the technique not to work anymore.